# C++ Sql Result Text

Tags: c++, mysql

Hey i am trying to get a text from sql with dwName but didin't work. The rest are int. Can someone explain me why this didin't work? I was trying to make int and like = player_id->GetName() but that wasn't working.

```
{
    ch->ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_COMMAND, "top_rank_open");
    int iLine = 0;
    MYSQL_ROW mRow;
    while (NULL != (mRow = mysql_fetch_row(pMsg->Get()->pSQLResult)))
    {
        int iCur = 0;
        char dwName[CHARACTER_NAME_MAX_LEN + 1];
        DWORD dwRace = 0, dwKing = 0, dwLevel = 0, dwDmg = 0, dwDate = 0;
        str_to_number(dwRace, mRow[iCur++]);
        str_to_number(dwKing, mRow[iCur++]);
        str_to_number(dwName, mRow[iCur++]);
        snprintf(dwName, sizeof(dwName), mRow[iCur++]);
        str_to_number(dwLevel, mRow[iCur++]);
        str_to_number(dwDmg, mRow[iCur++]);
        str_to_number(dwDate, mRow[iCur]);

        ch->ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_COMMAND, "top_rank_data #%d#%d#%d#%s#%d#%d#%d#", iLine, dwRace, dwKing, dwName, dwLevel, dwDmg, dwDate);
        ch->ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_INFO, "top_rank_data #%d#%d#%d#%s#%d#%d#%d#", iLine, dwRace, dwKing, dwName, dwLevel, dwDmg, dwDate);
        iLine++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger? Can you please elaborate on the "didin't [sic] work" part? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you probably want to learn about [the `std::stoi` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), instead of inventing your own function I mean.

Comment: I'd expect `str_to_number` to convert a string contained in the second parameter to a number and store it in the first one, right?. So why are you trying to convert a string not containing a integer value into a string? I think you want to do something like `strncpy(dwName, mRow[iCur++], CHARACTER_NAME_MAX_LEN + 1)`.

Comment: Also, you have a really big and dangerous security problem with the code you show, and that can lead to *undefined behavior* and god knows what problems: Think for a little while if the "name" contains `printf` formatting sequences? What happens then? Either use `strcpy` (or rather `strncpy`) as suggested by @muXXmit2X, or use e.g. `snprintf(dwName, sizeof(dwName), "%s", mRow[iCur++]);`

Comment: Oh and by the way, what if the "name" column is null? Have you checked for that? Or if it's simply empty?

Comment: Ohh i see i forgot to remove str_to_number(dwName, mRow[iCur++]);